# Push recyclerview above other layout while scrolling

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView to show list of images & FrameLayout which has id "fl_selectedImages" to show selected images which is at the bottom of the screen.

Framelayout fl_selectedImages has transparency in layout. So, while open the screen, we can see RecyclerView items at back.

But the problem is i can't scroll to the very bottom of the recyclerview. I want to force RecyclerView to scroll & pushed above the FrameLayout-fl_selectedImages while scrolling RecyclerView items.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/ScreenStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_3sdp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/emptyAlbum"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_110sdp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_gallery" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:text="@string/imagepicker_msg_no_images"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
                layout="@layout/banner_ad_layout" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_selectedImages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/selectedImages"
            layout="@layout/layout_selected" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` which adds to the last item a bottom offset so the `RecyclerView` can be pushed above of `"@+id/fl_selectedImages"` during scrolling to the bottom.

**Example:**

Declare a custom `BottomOffsetDecoration`:

```
class BottomOffsetDecoration(private val mBottomOffset: Int) : ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        val dataSize = state.itemCount
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        if (dataSize > 0 && position == dataSize - 1) {
            outRect[0, 0, 0] = mBottomOffset
        } else {
            outRect[0, 0, 0] = 0
        }
    }
}
```

And can be used in the `RecyclerView` like the below:

```
//change the bottom item offset of the last RecyclerView item based on your needs
val dps100ToPx = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100f, resources.displayMetrics)
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(BottomOffsetDecoration(dps100ToPx.toInt()))
```